# Some Huge Basic Thing Wrong -- "Cannot Find Element X"

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, saxparser, saxparseexception

My xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<credits> 
</credits>
```

My schema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="credits">

  </xsd:element>

</xsd:schema>
```

And it says "SaxParseException: cannot find declaration of element 'credits'"

What?! :P How is that possible? Absolutely confounded here. Been googling for hours nothing yet.

Thanks SO!

```
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance( XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI );
        Schema schemaXSD = schemaFactory.newSchema( new File ( "test.xsd" ) );

        Validator v = schemaXSD.newValidator();
       DocumentBuilder parser = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
  Document document = parser.parse( new File( "test.xml" ) );
        document.toString();
        DOMSource testSource = new DOMSource(document);
        v.validate( testSource );
```

EDIT:
Found the solution. Google finally yielded something. :P
I had to add

```
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

to my DocumentBuilderFactory object. :D

Comment: When entering XML (or any program code) use the `{}` button in the SO editor to indent it 4 spaces so SO formats it as code.  I fixed it for you.

Comment: Paste the relevant code of your Sax validation, as it is, I think both the XML and XSD are correct.

Comment: Updated with info requested. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

means that the test.xml doesn't have a `credits` element.  If this is acceptable, set `minOccurs="0"`

Comment: Try getting the file value as a text stream and see what it writes out.  It's possible you are not loading the correct file, or you are force-creating the file in a different directory than you think

Comment: Weird.  The issue is not with your XSD file.  It must be with SaxParser (not something I know about).  I retagged your question to help you get some people that can answer this

Comment: I've changed my document creation to be    Document document = parser.parse(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("test.xml")));

Comment: It didn't. ;) Sorry worded that wrong. I meant "the tags might help". It's for sure getting all the right data as well